# Insertar array en Mysql con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

En esta oportunidad les pido ayuda para poder ingresar un array.

Ya tengo la DB creada con los siguientes campos:

### id | nombre | umedida | precio | cant | stotal | igv | total | factura

El array tiene estos valores:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'umedida' => 'NIU',
    'cantidad' => '1',
    'stotal' => '123.00',
    'precio' => '104.24',
    'igv' => '18.76',
    'nombre' => '123n',
    'total' => 104.24,
    'factura' => '10101701',
  ),
  array (
    'umedida' => 'ZZ',
    'cantidad' => '1',
    'stotal' => '1213.00',
    'precio' => '1204.24',
    'igv' => '181.76',
    'nombre' => '123n',
    'total' => 104.24,
    'factura' => '10101701',
  ),
  array (
    'umedida' => 'ZZ',
    'cantidad' => '1',
    'stotal' => '133.00',
    'precio' => '134.24',
    'igv' => '181.76',
    'nombre' => '123n',
    'total' => 104.24,
    'factura' => '10101701',
  ),

);
```

La idea es que cada uno esté en una fila diferente ¿Como podría hacerlo?
De antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: ¿Has iniciado una conexión a la base de datos con php?

Answer (score 2):

Deacuerdo a tu pregunta, he realizado un codigo sencillo que permite leer tu array y luego insertarlo en una tabla en la base de datos.

Esta hecho en dos partes

```html
<?php
$salida = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'umedida' => 'NIU',
    'cantidad' => '1',
    'stotal' => '123.00',
    'precio' => '104.24',
    'igv' => '18.76',
    'nombre' => '123n',
    'total' => 104.24,
    'factura' => '10101701',
  ),
  array (
    'umedida' => 'ZZ',
    'cantidad' => '1',
    'stotal' => '1213.00',
    'precio' => '1204.24',
    'igv' => '181.76',
    'nombre' => '123n',
    'total' => 104.24,
    'factura' => '10101701',
  ),
  array (
    'umedida' => 'ZZ',
    'cantidad' => '1',
    'stotal' => '133.00',
    'precio' => '134.24',
    'igv' => '181.76',
    'nombre' => '123n',
    'total' => 104.24,
    'factura' => '10101701',
  ),

);


//
 // parametros de conexion
 $host ="localhost";
 $user ="grafimar_admin";
 $password ="anybody2015"; 
 $database = "pruebas";
// Crear conexion
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
// chequear
if (!$conn) {
      die("Falla de conexion !! " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "<br>Conexion exitosa!!";
 
// recorrido del array
for ($i=0; $i < count($salida) ; $i++) { 
    // asignacion de valores
    $umedida = $salida[$i]['umedida'];
    $cantidad = $salida[$i]['cantidad'];
    $stotal = $salida[$i]['stotal'];
    $precio = $salida[$i]['precio'];
    $igv = $salida[$i]['igv'];
    $nombre = $salida[$i]['nombre'];
    $total = $salida[$i]['total'];
    $factura =  $salida[$i]['factura'];
    // codigo SQL para insertar
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ventas (umedida, cantidad, stotal, precio, igv, nombre, total, factura)
    VALUES ('". $umedida ."', '". $cantidad ."', '". $stotal . "' , '". $precio . "' , '". $igv  . "', '". $nombre  . "' , '". $total  . "', '". $factura  . "')";
    // ejecucion del comando SQL 
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "<br> Nuevo Registro Creado item: ". $i;
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}

// cerrar conexion
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

El array es del tipo combinado entre numerico y asociativo por lo que para su lectura primero debes reccorre el valor posicional luego el nombre del item / llave para leer su valor: E: $salida[0]['umedida'] mostrara el valor 'NIU' mientras que $salida[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaeu0.jpg)['umedida']  mostrara 'ZZ'

En cuanto a la conexion a la BD esta es una de varias formas de hacerlo en PHP/MySQL

- El ciclo for() hace el recorrido el primer array y mediante la asignacion de variables se toma los valores para que corresponderan a cada regitro
- Se coloca la sintaxis SQL con los valores y sus campos y finalmente se ejecuta.

El resultado en pantalla y en la BD es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La carga en la BD

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]